# "\x{2019}" does not map to iso-8859-1 perl

Tags: perl

I have a string named $title

```
Gardens and Anti-Gardens in Marie de France’s <i>Lais</i>
```

and I am getting this error

```
"\x{2019}" does not map to iso-8859-1
```

I try removing the italic tags but it still gives me the error i.e.

```
$title =~ s/<i>|<\/i>//g;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think the HTML tags have anything to do with characters in the string?

If you google the `\x{2019}` [the first hit is this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).

> Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)

That's the `’`. Typically Microsoft Word converts apostrophes (single quotes `'`) to those kinds of quotation marks. It looks like you are trying to print your string somewhere where its converted to the ISO-8859-1 encoding. You should be able to specifically convert that character to something that makes more sense, like the above mentioned single quote `'`.

```
$string =~ s/\x{2019}/'/g;
```

That should get rid of that one warning. But if you import something with unicode and then expect it to be output as latin-1 more characters will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) does not contain the character U+2019.